# Unable to insert composite type via Java client to postgresql database: "value too long for type character(1)"

Tags: java, postgresql, composite-types

None of the existing answers seem to help the specific problem, which is - i have a table with a column of a composite type:

```
CREATE TYPE my_type AS (
    my_id INT4
    , my_other_id INT4
    , some_varchar VARCHAR(32)
    , is_true BOOL
    , some_char CHAR(1)
)
```

which is used in the table:

```
CREATE TABLE the_table
(
    id UUID
    , url VARCHAR(32)
    , name VARCHAR(32)
    , my_types _my_type NULL
)
```

And through java:

```
final String SQL = """
INSERT INTO the_table(
    id
    , url
    , name
    , my_types
)
VALUES (
    ?
    , ?
    , ?
    , ?
)
"""

// some stuff - like get connection
var statement = c.prepareStatement(SQL);
statement.setObject(1, model.getId());
statement.setObject(2, model.getUrl());
statement.setObject(3, model.getName());
statement.setObject(4, c.createArrayOf("my_type", model.getMyTypes());

// where the implementation of MyType::toString() is:
@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format("(%d, %d, '%s', %b, '%c'),
        this.getId(), 
        this.getOtherId(),
        this.getName(),
        this.getIsTrue(),
        this.getSomeChar());
```

PROBLEM: I cannot avoid getting the error: "Value too long for type character(1)" - even though getSomeChar() is definitely a single character. The only way I can get it to run without erroring is to do change the toString() to:

```
return String.format("(%d, %d, '%s', %b, \"\")
```

which of course doesn't do what i want it to do (the char is null), but it does prove it is at least possible to persist this composite type in this manner. i don't know what i am doing wrong, or why it despises my attempt to push a single character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends on which encoding you are using for your characters (and which characters `getSomeChar` can return). From this [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/multibyte.html) , some encodings, like utf-8, expect to have upto char(4) allocated to store a single character. Changing to `CHAR(4)` should cover all possible encodings:

```
CREATE TYPE my_type AS (
my_id INT4
, my_other_id INT4
, some_varchar VARCHAR(32)
, is_true BOOL
, some_char CHAR(4)
```

)

Comment: did think that - i tried the lazy way which was to set CLIENT_ENCODING to SQL_ASCII, but that raised a bunch of errors. what i do not understand is why DBeaver client doesn't have the same problem - no issue to INSERT ... VALUES(ROW(1, 1, 'hi', 0, 'A')::my_type) with DBeaver, despite the encoding being set to UTF-8 (client and db). i'll try it out tho.

Comment: getSomeChar() will always be in ASCII range - either lowercase or uppercase: [A-Z|a-z]

Comment: char(3) it is :/